# How to map one property to another using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a User Class:

```
public class User {
    public int UserId {get; set;}
    public string Username {get; set;}
    }
```

I'm trying to add an `Email` property that `gets` and `sets` the `Username` property - they're the same thing, but I don't need to add another physical property to the model, just a reference.

I know this means I have to use a custom get and set, but I'm stuck with the syntax.  Those terms are so ambiguous so I haven't had much luck pulling anything relevant up. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SOmething like this you mean?

```
public string Email 
{
   get
   {
      return this.Usename;
   }
   set
   {
      this.Username = value;
   }
}
```

Comment: 2 minutes, crazy.  Exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you

Comment: @RobVious, also, you don't need to define both `set` and `get` unless you really want to.

Answer (score 2):

It should look a bit like this:

```
public class User 
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Email 
    {
        get { return this.Username; }
        set { this.Username = value; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class User {
    public int UserId {get; set;}
    public string Username {get; set;}
    public string Email{
        get
        {
            return UserId;
        }
        set 
        {
            UserId = value;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Public Class User
{
   private string username;
   private string email;

   public string GetUsername()
   {
       return this.username;
   }

   public void SetUsername(string parUsername)
   {
       return this.username = parUsername;
   }

}
```

Comment: This is a *dramatic* change to design of the class. It doesn't come close to accomplishing what OP wants. And on top of that, it doesn't even compile.